# MobileFirst: issue in calling an adapter without login after adding mobileSecurityTest

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters

I had a security test for login which is as below

```
<customSecurityTest name="SingleStepAuthAdapter-securityTest">
            <test isInternalUserID="true" realm="SingleStepAuthRealm"/>
        </customSecurityTest>
<realm loginModule="AuthLoginModule" name="SingleStepAuthRealm">
          <className>com.worklight.integration.auth.AdapterAuthenticator</className>
          <parameter name="login-function" value="AuthenticationService.onAuthRequired"/>
          <parameter name="logout-function" value="AuthenticationService.onLogout"/>
        </realm>
```

I have adapters that have to be called before login and they work fine until I am putthis piece of code in my authenticationConfig.xml for pushnotification

```
<mobileSecurityTest name="PushApplication-strong-mobile-securityTest">
        <testUser realm="SingleStepAuthRealm"/>
        <testDeviceId provisioningType="none"/>
        </mobileSecurityTest>
```

The adapters that are called before login like forgot password are not working and not giving any error.Can any help me in understanding why this issue exits, do I need to put some wl_unprotected in these adapters.Because I have tried that to. Do I need to do any thing else.I can give you more details if you need something else.

Please help.

Comment: Is your application protected by a security test? Or only specific adapters? Are you testing on a browser or on a mobile device? Show us which adapter uses which security test.

Comment: can you  give us your whole authenticationConfig file so that we can check if you are doing anything wrong there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the solution ..

I was putting security test for whole android app when I removed it worked for me...

instead of this..

```
<android version="1.0" securityTest="PushApplication-strong-mobile-securityTest">
```

using this worked

```
<android version="1.0" >
```